# Dynamic top 3 and percentage total using pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
id,Name,country,amount,qty
1,ABC,USA,123,4500
1,ABC,USA,156,3210
1,BCE,USA,687,2137
1,DEF,UK,456,1236
1,ABC,nan,216,324
1,DEF,nan,12678,11241
1,nan,nan,637,213
1,BCE,nan,213,543
1,XYZ,KOREA,432,321
1,XYZ,AUS,231,321

sf = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
```

I would like to do the below

a) Get top 3 based on `amount` **for each id and other selected columns such as `Name` and `country`**. Meaning, we get top 3 based `id and Name` first and later, we again get top 3 based on `id and country`

b) Find out how much does each of the top 3 item contribute to `total amount` for each unique id.

So, I tried the below

```
sf_name = sf.groupby(['id','Name'],dropna=False)['amount'].sum().nlargest(3).reset_index().rename(columns={'amount':'Name_amount'})
sf_country = sf.groupby(['id','country'],dropna=False)['amount'].sum().nlargest(3).reset_index().rename(columns={'amount':'country_amount'})
sf_name['total'] = sf.groupby('id')['amount'].sum()
sf_country['total'] = sf.groupby('id')['amount'].sum()
sf_name['name_pct_total'] = (sf_name['Name_amount']/sf_name['total'])*100
sf_country['country_pct_total'] = (sf_country['country_amount']/sf_country['total'])*100
```

As you can see, I am repeating the same operation for each column.

But in my real dataframe, I have to do this groupby `id` and find Top3 and compute `pct_total` % for another 8 columns (along with `Name` and `country`)

Is there any efficient, elegant and scalable solution that you can share?

I expect my output to be like as below

[image]

**update - full error**

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\Test\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8720/1850446854.py in <module>
----> 1 df_new.groupby(['unique_key','Resale Customer'],dropna=False)['Revenue Resale EUR'].sum().nlargest(3).reset_index(level=1, name=f'{c}_revenue')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in nlargest(self, n, keep)
   3834         dtype: int64
   3835         """
-> 3836         return algorithms.SelectNSeries(self, n=n, keep=keep).nlargest()
   3837 
   3838     def nsmallest(self, n: int = 5, keep: str = "first") -> Series:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py in nlargest(self)
   1135     @final
   1136     def nlargest(self):
-> 1137         return self.compute("nlargest")
   1138 
   1139     @final

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\algorithms.py in compute(self, method)
   1181 
   1182         dropped = self.obj.dropna()
-> 1183         nan_index = self.obj.drop(dropped.index)
   1184 
   1185         if is_extension_array_dtype(dropped.dtype):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    309                     stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310                 )
--> 311             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    312 
    313         return wrapper

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in drop(self, labels, axis, index, columns, level, inplace, errors)
   4769         dtype: float64
   4770         """
-> 4771         return super().drop(
   4772             labels=labels,
   4773             axis=axis,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in drop(self, labels, axis, index, columns, level, inplace, errors)
   4277         for axis, labels in axes.items():
   4278             if labels is not None:
-> 4279                 obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, errors=errors)
   4280 
   4281         if inplace:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _drop_axis(self, labels, axis, level, errors, consolidate, only_slice)
   4321                 new_axis = axis.drop(labels, level=level, errors=errors)
   4322             else:
-> 4323                 new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
   4324             indexer = axis.get_indexer(new_axis)
   4325 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py in drop(self, codes, level, errors)
   2234         for level_codes in codes:
   2235             try:
-> 2236                 loc = self.get_loc(level_codes)
   2237                 # get_loc returns either an integer, a slice, or a boolean
   2238                 # mask

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py in get_loc(self, key, method)
   2880         if keylen == self.nlevels and self.is_unique:
   2881             try:
-> 2882                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2883             except TypeError:
   2884                 # e.g. test_partial_slicing_with_multiindex partial string slicing

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.BaseMultiIndexCodesEngine.get_loc()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.UInt64HashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.UInt64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 8937472
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpliest is use loop by columnsnames in list, for `pct_amount` use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `sum` per `id` and divide `amount` column:

```
dfs = []
cols = ['Name','country']

for c in cols:
    df = (sf.groupby(['id',c],dropna=False)['amount'].sum()
            .nlargest(3)
            .reset_index(level=1, name=f'{c}_amount'))

    df[f'{c}_pct_total']=(df[f'{c}_amount'].div(df.groupby('id',dropna=False)[f'{c}_amount']
                                            .transform('sum'))*100)
    dfs.append(df)
    
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
print (df)
   Name  Name_amount  Name_pct_total country  country_amount  \
id                                                             
1   DEF        13134       89.365177     NaN           13744   
1   BCE          900        6.123699     USA             966   
1   XYZ          663        4.511125      UK             456   

    country_pct_total  
id                     
1           90.623764  
1            6.369511  
1            3.006726
```

Testing with `Resale Customer` column name::

```
print (sf)
   id Resale Customer country  amount    qty
0   1             ABC     USA     123   4500
1   1             ABC     USA     156   3210
2   1             BCE     USA     687   2137
3   1             DEF      UK     456   1236
4   1             ABC     NaN     216    324
5   1             DEF     NaN   12678  11241
6   1             NaN     NaN     637    213
7   1             BCE     NaN     213    543
8   1             XYZ   KOREA     432    321
9   1             XYZ     AUS     231    321
```

Test columns names:

```
print (sf.columns)
Index(['id', 'Resale Customer', 'country', 'amount', 'qty'], dtype='object')

dfs = []
cols = ['Resale Customer','country']

for c in cols:
    df = (sf.groupby(['id',c],dropna=False)['amount'].sum()
            .nlargest(3)
            .reset_index(level=1, name=f'{c}_amount'))

    df[f'{c}_pct_total']=(df[f'{c}_amount'].div(df.groupby('id',dropna=False)[f'{c}_amount']
                                            .transform('sum'))*100)
    dfs.append(df)
    
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
print (df)
   Resale Customer  Resale Customer_amount  Resale Customer_pct_total country  \
id                                                                              
1              DEF                   13134                  89.365177     NaN   
1              BCE                     900                   6.123699     USA   
1              XYZ                     663                   4.511125      UK   

    country_amount  country_pct_total  
id                                     
1            13744          90.623764  
1              966           6.369511  
1              456           3.006726
```

Solution with melt is possible, but more complicated:

```
df = sf.melt(id_vars=['id', 'amount'], value_vars=['Name','country'])
df = (df.groupby(['id','variable', 'value'],dropna=False)['amount']
        .sum()
        .sort_values(ascending=False)
        .groupby(level=[0,1],dropna=False)
        .head(3)
        .to_frame()
        .assign(pct_total=lambda x: x['amount'].div(x.groupby(level=[0,1],dropna=False)['amount'].transform('sum')).mul(100),
                g=lambda x: x.groupby(level=[0,1],dropna=False).cumcount())
        .set_index('g', append=True)
        .reset_index('value')
        .unstack(1)
        .sort_index(level=1, axis=1)
        .droplevel(1)
        )

df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[1]}_{x[0]}')

print (df)
    Name_amount  Name_pct_total Name_value  country_amount  country_pct_total  \
id                                                                              
1         13134       89.365177        DEF           13744          90.623764   
1           900        6.123699        BCE             966           6.369511   
1           663        4.511125        XYZ             456           3.006726   

   country_value  
id                
1            NaN  
1            USA  
1             UK
```

Comment: but one issue. when I try this in real data, I get an error `KeyError: 8937472`

Comment: @TheGreat - what step?

Comment: ``df = sf.groupby(['id',c],dropna=False)['amount'].sum().nlargest(3).reset_index(level=1, name=f'{c}_amount')`

Comment: @TheGreat - for test if use only `sf.groupby(['id',c],dropna=False)['amount'].sum()` it working?

Comment: No. It is not worki8ng but now the error is in line `df[f'{c}_pct_total'] = df[f'{c}_amount'].div(df.groupby('unique_key')[f'{c}_amount'].transform('sum'))*100`

Comment: Error is `keyerror : Resale Customer_amount`. One of my groupby column name is `Resale Customer` (with space in between)..

Comment: @TheGreat - I think is necessary add `dropna=False` to each `groupby`

Comment: @TheGreat - I can test `Resale Customer`

Comment: Actually, it works well for some columns when I do one by one manually. Do you know when can a `Keyerror` happen?  is it due to the values in certain columns?

Comment: Meaning, when I replace `c` in for loop by column name, manually, it works well for 4 columns and fails for 3 columns. and those 3 columns have a key error with some random number

Comment: @TheGreat - what columnsnames failed? with spaces? and which working?

Comment: spaces is not issue. I tried with other columns which has spaces and it worked. for some column name with spaces, it throws key error

Comment: @TheGreat - Honestly not idea. It seems some problem with data, what is rows with index=8937472 ?

Comment: when I try `df_new.iloc[[8937472]]`, it gives another error - `IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds`. my df len is only 376712

Comment: @TheGreat - try `df_new.loc[[8937472]]`

Comment: I get this error `KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([8937472], dtype='int64')] are in the [index]"`

Comment: @TheGreat - what is `print (df.index)` ? It is RangeIndex? If not, maybe help `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: One last question. melt approach works correctly. but why is the `pct_total` value in decimals (0.009062) despite you use `mul(100)`. Shouldn't it be 90.62? If I manually mutiply by 100, it is still only `0.9062` incorrect. Isn't it?

Comment: @TheGreat - you are right, I multiple before `), now it is correct.

Comment: No, what I meant was, your code when executed produces output in decimal points `0.009062` etc. `Mul` is not working

Comment: @TheGreat - do you change `.transform('sum').mul(100))` to `.transform('sum')).mul(100)` ?